# tar.gz issues, would ALIEN work on Ubuntu or Lubuntu

Tags: printing, deb, tar

I've been using Linux for a long time and I love it, until I have to install TAR.GZ software. The forums are very confusing on Tar.GZ files.

I've heard that it's possible to convert the file to a very simple to install DEB file.
I was told that if I install the package called ALIEN I can convert it to a DEB file, once I have a DEB file I can just double click on it to get it working. Is this true?

I was told it was as easy as this:

1. CD to the folder with the file
2. sudo apt-get install alien
3. sudo alien -d filename.tar.gz
4. This creates a DEB file, click on it to install.

Is this is correct?

I have and Lubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20 on another system.

Comment: Alien is used to convert simpler rpm packages into deb (and back). It can be used for .tar.gz *packages* (like in Slackware) but cannot be used for ordinary .tar.gz *compressed files* (like family photos and other data). Of course, it does not need to be so used, anyway.

Comment: FYI, Ubuntu 20 is off topic; only currently supported releases are on-topic. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic states _Questions that you should avoid... 
 Issues with the next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1) (More information about Alpha and Beta release issues)_